# Do primes dividing a polynomial follow a modular law?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Given a monic integer coefficient polynomial $P$, does the set of primes dividing $P(x)$ for some $x$ follow a modular distrubiton except finitely many exceptions? For example for $P(x)=x^2+1$, the set is the primes of the form $4k+1$ and $2$.

I tried to search it on the internet but I only found stuff about the distribution like Chebotarev density.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  Why isn't the [Chebotarev Density Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebotarev%27s_density_theorem) an answer to your question?

Comment: The answer is yes if the Galois group of the polynomial is abelian. Without class field theory there is not much to explain.

Comment: @franzlemmermeyer so is there a polynomial not satisfying this property?

Comment: @lulu As I understand, it only deals with the density of the distribution rather than the distribution itself

Comment: Ah.  Well, [here](https://oeis.org/A040028) is the sequence of primes for which $x^3-2$ has a root, just as an example.  Obviously, you get every prime of the form $3n+2$ but you also get all the primes representable by a particular quadratic form.  It's hard to say much about general polynomials.  At least $S_3$ is solvable.